# Android - Send SMS and make the text not editable

Tags: android, sms

```
                String number = "0707775544";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(number);
                Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello world!");
                startActivity(smsIntent);
```

When I run this code, Android's default SMS opens up and I can of course send this. My question is: is there anyway I can make the the text "Hello world!" NOT editable, and if you want to write a personal message, it gets below this "Hello world!".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i got the question right, [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) is your solution. 
[This tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) might also be usefull.

Comment: Alright, so then I need to implement a SMS layout myself and also the attach part. I was hoping there was another way :P

Comment: There might be, but none that I know about

Comment: Alright, I'll keep looking or hoping for someone to answer to this question. But thanks Vladimir!

Answer (score 0):

see this tutorial

http://android10.org/index.php/articlesfullapplications/241-sms-messaging-in-android-send-and-receive

you can customize the layout to disable the part you don't want changed then send the message directly

Comment: It's the same as Vladimir suggested. I want to be able to do this by using Android's default SMS, not creating one myself.