# Sms intent with non editable message body

Tags: java, android

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");           
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",sMessage);
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

It is working fine. But I want to open non editable message body. User can only select the number to whom he/she wants to send the message

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834134/android-send-sms-and-make-the-text-not-editable)

Comment: I don't want to use SMSManager class. As I have to create another layout for that.

Comment: Can't I write anything in putExtra ?

Comment: there is NO way to do that with smsManager.  You must do what Sanket has kindly explained.

Answer (score 2):

You can try different way then intent.Like using directly sms to recipient's number and display the message in your own view.

Code to send SMS directly to phone number :

```
private void sendAutoSms(String phonenumber,String message, boolean isBinary)
{
SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();

PendingIntent intentSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMS_SENT), 0);
PendingIntent intentDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED), 0);

if(isBinary)
{
        byte[] data = new byte[message.length()];

        for(int index=0; index<message.length() && index < MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH; ++index)
        {
                data[index] = (byte)message.charAt(index);
        }

        manager.sendDataMessage(phonenumber, null, (short) SMS_PORT, data,intentSend, intentDelivered);
}
else
{
        int length = message.length();

        if(length > MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH)
        {
                ArrayList<String> messagelist = manager.divideMessage(message);

                manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phonenumber, null, messagelist, null, null);
        }
        else
        {
                manager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, intentSend, intentDelivered);
        }
}
}
```

Include Permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: with this way I have to create my own layout. and also I have to fetch user's contacts to provide the facility of autocomplete to search the contact whom the user wants to send the message

Comment: Else there is no way to handle system service

Comment: You have to do some self work for this as you want to custom things and you dont want to do anything then that is not possible sorry